# problemas con un insert php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

buen dia
resulta que tengo un problema respecto a un repositorio que descarge en github
el cual viene con un crud de imagenes
ahora
todo agarra bien sin embargo
tiene dos problemas que ya me cance de buscar la solucion
uno de ellos es que cuadno le doy al boton de agregar una imagen nueva con descripcion este o que hace es un UPDATE a la base de datos y borra en anterior apsesar de que tiene el insert
el segundo problema es que cuando quiero agregar uno nuevo en el mismo boton de agregar imagen me aparece la ultima imagen que actualice y no me permite agregar cosas nuevas
agrego el insert del boton agregar

```
<?php
session_start();
$title="Agregar Banner";
/* Llamar la Cadena de Conexion*/ 
include ("../conexion.php");
//Insert un nuevo producto
$imagen_demo="demo.png";
$insert=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO banner (url_image, estado) values ('$imagen_demo','0')");
$sql_last=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(id) as last from banner order by id desc limit 0,1");
$rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_last);
$id_banner=intval($rw['last']);
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from banner where id='$id_banner' limit 0,1");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($count==0){
    //header("location: bannerlist.php");
    //exit;
}
$rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$titulo=$rw['titulo'];
$descripcion=$rw['descripcion'];
$url_image=$rw['url_image'];
$orden=intval($rw['orden']);
$estado=intval($rw['estado']);

$active_config="active";
$active_banner="active";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../images/ico/favicon.ico">
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/preview-image.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
        <?php include("top_menu.php");?>

    <div class="container">
        
      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="row">
 
       <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="bannerlist.php">Banner</a></li>
          <li class="active">Editar</li>
        </ol>
         <div class="col-md-7">
         <h3 ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar banner</h3>
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="editar_banner">
                 
             
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="titulo" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Titulo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" value="<?php echo $titulo;?>" required name="titulo">
                  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id_banner" value="<?php echo intval($id_banner);?>" name="id_banner">
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="titulo" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Descripción</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <textarea class='form-control' name="descripcion" id="descripcion" required rows=8><?php echo $descripcion;?></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>    
              
            
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="orden" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Orden</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="orden" name="orden" value="<?php echo $orden;?>">
                </div>
              </div>
              
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="estado" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Estado</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <select class="form-control" id="estado" required name="estado">
                    <option value="0" <?php if($estado==0){echo "selected";} ?>>Inactivo</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php if($estado==1){echo "selected";} ?>>Activo</option>
                 </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            
             
              
              
              <div class="form-group">
              <div id='loader'></div>
              <div class='outer_div'></div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Actualizar datos</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            
            
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
         <h3 ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Imagen</h3>
         
         <form class="form-vertical">
         
            <div class="form-group">
                
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                
                 
                 <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                                  <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="max-width: 100%;" >
                                      <img class="img-rounded" src="../img/banner/<?php echo $url_image;?>" />
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 250px; max-height: 250px;"></div>
                                  <div>
                                    <span class="btn btn-info btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Selecciona una imagen</span>
                                    <span class="fileinput-exists" onclick="upload_image();">Cambiar imagen</span><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" required onchange="upload_image();"></span>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Cancelar</a>
                                  </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="upload-msg"></div>
                    
                </div>
                
              </div>
              
            
              
             
              
              
         </form>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </div><!-- /container -->

        <?php include("footer.php");?>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
    <script>
            function upload_image(){
                $(".upload-msg").text('Cargando...');
                var id_banner=$("#id_banner").val();
                var inputFileImage = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
                var file = inputFileImage.files[0];
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('fileToUpload',file);
                data.append('id',id_banner);
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/upload_banner.php",        // Url to which the request is send
                    type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
                    data: data,               // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                    contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                    cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
                    processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                    success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                    {
                        $(".upload-msg").html(data);
                        window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".alert-dismissible").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                        }); }, 5000);
                    }
                });
                
            }
            
            function eliminar(id){
                var parametros = {"action":"delete","id":id};
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'ajax/upload2.php',
                            data: parametros,
                             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                            $(".upload-msg2").text('Cargando...');
                          },
                            success:function(data){
                                $(".upload-msg2").html(data);
                                
                            }
                        })
                    
                }
                
                
                
                
            
    </script>
    <script>
        $("#editar_banner").submit(function(e) {
            
              $.ajax({
                  url: "ajax/editar_banner.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: $("#editar_banner").serialize(),
                   beforeSend: function(objeto){
                    $("#loader").html("Cargando...");
                  },
                  success:function(data){
                        $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                        $("#loader").html("");
                    }
            });
             e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Realmente tu forma de plantear la pregunta es confusa. Dedícale un poco de tiempo a la pregunta para explicar el problema. Hablas por ejemplo de que ocurre un UPDATE pero en el código no aparece ese UPDATE. Quizá deberías revisar despacio el flujo de tu programa y comprender lo que ocurre en cada etapa del mismo haciendo las depuraciones que sean necesarias.

Comment: ocurre el update en vez del insert es decir no me permite guardar un nuevo registro solamente avctualiza el id 22 y los agrega en ese mismo id ligado